# How to create background for play and pause buttons using xml drawables?

Tags: android, xml-drawable, layer-list

I'm going to use two `ImageButtons` in my app:**Play** and **Pause** buttons, I want to achieve the proper backgrounds using `xml drawables`, I played around with `layer-list` for hours but didn't figure out how to use scale and rotate to have a triangle with the desired rotation, neither the pause rects, also checked previous questions and unfortunately didn't help too much,How can I have the exact shapes in xml like image below?
[image]

Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `FloatingActionButton` in android support design library. It is in circle shape , and place the play and pause image in center of it.
[Documentation for FloatingActionButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)
I don't know why you want to rotate your play and pause buttons , but you can rotate views in android with this code:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
fab.animate().setRotation(90f);
```

P.s. this `setRotation()` method is made available after API 10

Comment: Thanks for the respond, And I'm sure there's lots of better approaches to do this like you suggest and is much more easier, But let's just  say it's a like a pratice for me ;-)

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/

complete example for using a FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 0):

use the inbuilt `drawable icon'

```
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/selected_icon"
```

This will give you a list of icon available in the android library. you can completely remove the background so that you have the icon centralized.